# Why can't extract Json Array in java?

Tags: java, android, json, loops

I have a Restaurant List Object and also have a Cuisine List Object in that Restaurant List. How to Loop to show all cuisine data (New American, Japanese, Asia).

```
public class RestaurantList {

    @SerializedName("restaurant_id")
    @Expose
    private String restaurantId;
    @SerializedName("restaurant_name")
    @Expose
    private String restaurantName;
    @SerializedName("cuisine")
    @Expose
    private List<Cuisine> cuisine = null;

    public List<Cuisine> getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(List<Cuisine> cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
}
```

In Restaurant RVAdapter, onBindViewHolder();

```
List<RestaurantList> mRestaurantList;

            List<Cuisine> cuisineList = restaurantList.getCuisine();
            String strCuisine = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < cuisineList.size(); i++) {
                strCuisine.concat(cuisineList.get(i).getCuisineName());
                strCuisine.concat(",");
                Log.i("Cuisine", cuisineList.get(i).getCuisineName());
                holder.tv_restaurant_cuisine.setText(" " + cuisineList.get(i).getCuisineName());
            }
```

Json Array;

```
[
  {...},
  {
    "restaurant_id": "41",
    "restaurant_name": "Shwe Lar Food Restaurant",
    "cuisine": [
      {
        "cuisine_name": "New American"
      },
      {
        "cuisine_name": "Japanese"
      },
      {
        "cuisine_name": "Asia"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Below Method to parse your data:
I remove last , after array and {...}

```
 private void parseJson(String jsonDataResponse){
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataResponse);

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String restaurant_id = jsonObject1.optString("restaurant_id");
                String restaurant_name = jsonObject1.optString("restaurant_name");

                JSONArray jsonArray1 =jsonObject1.getJSONArray("cuisine");

                System.out.println("restaurant_id="+restaurant_id);
                System.out.println("restaurant_name="+restaurant_name);

                for(int j=0;j<jsonArray1.length();j++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                    String cuisine_name = jsonObject2.optString("cuisine_name");
                    System.out.println("cuisine_name="+cuisine_name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how to set in TextView?

Comment: Have you created RestaurantList  as you put in your question from json parsing method as i given you . if yes then you can get values and set to any textview like tv.setText(list.getRestaurantName());

Comment: What is jsonDataResponse ? Where is it come from? I don't know exactly, Please Sir..

Comment: its your jsonArray in from of String  , you can pass your jsonString  that is you can found from you database or network .

Comment: [
  {...},
  {
    "restaurant_id": "41",
    "restaurant_name": "Shwe Lar Food Restaurant",
    "cuisine": [
      {
        "cuisine_name": "New American"
      },
      {
        "cuisine_name": "Japanese"
      },
      {
        "cuisine_name": "Asia"
      }
    ],
  }
]

Comment: Yes, api path ?

Comment: where did you get above json response?

Comment: so are you able to retrieve response from above link?